# Azure Container Instances - Expose port to bind on 443 (HTTPS)

Tags: azure, azure-container-instances

I have an image that defaults to a port, doesn't seem to have the option to expose it within the image.

If I need to, can you expose the listening port and bind it to a different port through the Container Instance?

For example:

Listening 8099 -> 443 (HTTPS Traffic)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you cannot achieve this as you do in docker. You just can choose which port to expose when you create the Azure container instance. And there is also no property to do that with Azure CLI command [`az container create`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/container?view=azure-cli-latest#az-container-create).

If you want to expose the port 443, just use the command like this:

```
az container create -g resourceGroupName --name aciName --image yourImage --ip-address public --ports 443
```

Comment: In which case we'd have to build our own image to ensure the port is exposed. Thanks, I thought this was the case. Shame really.